# What exactly does the setArgument and getArgument method do?

Tags: java, android

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

I am confuse about the code above where the fragment has something called `setArguments(args)`.

I am not exactly sure what exactly does this `setArguments(args) and I also want to know what does the getArgument() method do since I saw it while looking at the developer.android.com.

Comment: Did you read the javadoc for those two methods?

Comment: If the page has no value, that bundle object will pass default value as a page value.

Answer (score 0):

Used to pass data to fragment, and in the Fragment code, you can call `getArguments()` to get what you passed to it.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly then setArgument allows me to pass a bundle object to that fragment object to store for data right? but what I have above is that the mPager integer has no value right?